# Allow update only from uid in the document (firestore security rules)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Lets imagine I have an "offer" document which has the original creator saved with his uid
as a field called "uid" as well.

How can I modify the following rules to allow only the user whose request.auth.uid matches to that one in the document field update the document ?

Here are my rules for now

```
function signedInOrPublic() {
  return request.auth.uid != null;     
}     

match /offer/{offerDcoument} {       
  allow read: if request.auth.uid != null 
  allow create: if signedInOrPublic() 
  allow update: <ONLY ALLOW IF THE UID FIELD MATCHES request.auth.uid CONDITION>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the field using `resource` object:

```js
match /offer/{offerDcoument} {       
  allow read: if request.auth.uid != null 
  allow create: if signedInOrPublic() 
  allow update: if request.auth != null && resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
                                                      // ^^^ fieldname
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm 