# How to lock updating/deleting a collection created by a user to the same user who created the collection in firestore (without using cloud Functions)?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following model and rules... the first part of the equation is working fine a user can CRUD his own collection that he created, and it has the the same id as the creator.

the issue lies in the other collection that created by that user since it has a different id (an autogenerated id by firestore and I want to lock this collection to by modified only by the user that created it) any idea how to do this ?

```js
Collections Model

// Data   // doc id === uid
subDataId: null,
createdAt: Timestamp.now(),
            
// Sub Data // doc id === generated automatically by fb refrenced in the data collection. 
online: false,
createdAt: Timestamp.now(),

// Firebase rules 

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /Data/{userId} {
    allow read , create: if request.auth != null
    allow update, delete : if request.auth.uid == userId
    }
    
    match /SubData/{SubDataId} {
        allow read , create: if request.auth != null
       //  allow update : if request.auth.uid == ?????????
 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a rule that requires the user to provide their own user ID as a field of the document being created (see the [documentation about requiring that a field is provided](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#requiring_specific_fields_in_new_documents)).  Make sure the code in your app does exactly that.  Also write a rule that checks if the user id of the user updating the document also matches the field that was previously written by that user.

You might want to [read this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68564316/allow-update-only-from-uid-in-the-document-firestore-security-rules) as well.